# Building a new rig: will a 9800 GT work well for my needs?

Tags: 10.10, nvidia

I'm in the process of pricing out and purchasing components for a new computer, and I wanted to make sure that my selections will run as expected in my planned install of Ubuntu 10.10 x64.  Right now I'm looking at this GPU and motherboard:

- [EVGA 512-P3-N982-B2 GeForce 9800 GT Akimbo](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=6820707&sku=D69-9800)
- [Gigabyte GA-880GM-UD2H](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003DM5CH8)

I'm including the motherboard just in case I've made some gross oversight and these two components aren't compatible, or my novice-level knowledge of Linux shines through and I've missed something entirely about how the Linux kernel interacts with bits of the motherboard.

One can never be too careful.

My gaming habits are limited to Minecraft and potentially WoW, and to be honest I'll probably have a Windows partition for running WoW anyway until I double the planned 4GB of RAM (I've already selected a quad-core CPU).  In any case I'm not the type of gamer who runs the latest games at 1920x1080 resolution with all the settings on max.  I'm more interested in smoothness than flashy graphics.

My question boils down to this: **Will this GPU run properly and allow me to play something like Minecraft with a respectable level of performance?  Additionally, how will WoW perform?**

I would also be greatly appreciative of any random advice that you may have to offer on this matter, as I'd rather not leave any stone unturned before I make my purchases.

Comment: Use the 9800GT myself, with the proprietary drivers, never had a problem. Both WoW and Minecraft work fine =) In fact, Dragon Age 2 runs with max graphics (no AA) as well, I only tested that in Windows though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I haven't gotten a suitable response, but I *have* received my hardware and installed Ubuntu 10.10 x64 on it and been using it for a few days now I can safely answer this question:

**The hardware I chose is fully capable of doing everything I wanted it to do.**  Minecraft runs beautifully full-screened (1920x1080) with max settings, and while I haven't installed WoW via Wine or a VM I do know that in a pinch I can repartition my HDD and install Windows XP and it will run like a dream.

**Edit:** I've now installed WoW using Wine and I can confirm that it runs beautifully.

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to play Minecraft awesomely. In my personal experience with Minecraft (Server Admin). It's most important to have at least 4GB and a quad core processor. Other than that, everything should be exactly what you need.